# Tab Bar Within a Scroll View

Tags: swift, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller

I need to be able to have a scrollable view that contains Tab Bar and two views. The Tab Bar is only supposed to show on the first view; when you swipe right to get to the second view, the tab bar shouldn't be there. (Its supposed to work exactly like Instagram's stories where you can slide to get to the camera on the home screen). Right now I have the scrollable container view embedded in the tab bar controller and I added the two views to the container view within its class. However the Tab Bar is on the bottom of both views.

[container view embedded in tab bar controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cat5S.png)

[code for container view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mys5x.png)

Does anyone have a solution to fix This?

Comment: Have you tried using `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.zPosition = -1` when you reach the second view?

Comment: An `UIPageViewController` might do the trick here

Comment: @BenjaminLowry should I try putting that in a view did appear method?

Comment: Whatever you are using to detect the scrollView subView change is appropriate to put that in.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Thanks!